# Surprise results iterating over an array with an optional in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I was surprised that this swift code behaves nicely:

```
let values = ["Hello", "Test"]

var count = 0
for string: String in values {
    count = count + 1
    print("count is: ", count)
    print(string)
}
```

with output of:

```
count is:  1
Hello
count is:  2
Test
```

but making the String into String? creates an infinite loop.

```
   let values = ["Hello", "Test"]

    var count = 0
    for string: String? in values {
        count = count + 1
        print("count is: ", count)
        print(string)
    }
```

with output of:

```
count is:  1
Optional("Hello")
count is:  2
Optional("Test")
count is:  3
nil
count is:  4
nil
count is:  5
nil
count is:  6
nil
count is:  7
nil
count is:  8
(ad infinitum)
```

Swift has been so good at catching weird code problems that I was surprised I could walk into such a mess without warning or error.
Is this really what one would expect from Swift 4? And if so, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand this issue it helps to recollect how for-in loops work:

```
for s in values {
    print(s)
}
```

creates an *iterator* of the sequence, and calls the iterator's `next()` method until that returns `nil`:

```
var it = values.makeIterator()
while let s = it.next() {
    print(s)
}
```

Your second version is equivalent to

```
var it = values.makeIterator()
while let s: String? = it.next() {
    print(s)
}
```

and now the compiler warns:

```
warning: explicitly specified type 'String?' adds an additional level
of optional to the initializer, making the optional check always succeed
    while let s: String? = it.next() {
          ^      ~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~
                 String
```

So what happens here is that the `String?` returned from `it.next()`
is wrapped into a “nested optional” `.some(it.next())` of type `String??`, which is then optionally bound to `s: String?`.
This does always succeed, because `.some(it.next())` is not `String??.none`.
Therefore the loop never terminates.

One could argue that the compiler should warn as well for

```
for s: String? in values {
    print(s)
}
```

Comment: A breath of fresh air as always! (*There should be a ❤️reaction in SO*)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" runs on indexes. Under the index in excess of the number of elements is nill.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a deeper answer.  There are only 2 items in the array, why would it iterate past the two?  And if it really thinks that hanging around in an infinite loop is such a great idea, why doesn't it warn me?

Comment: If you write "while true" it also does not warn.

Comment: Actually “for-in” does not use indexes at all. It works with *sequences” which do not even have an index.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error. In the first function it will keep going until it no more strings.

But other hand the second function you set the string to optional so when its no more string it will still keep going. Because nil is a nil value and it’s not the same as nothing.  You have nothing that ends that loop.

Comment: Yes, I see that that is what is happening.  I'm just surprised that swift lets it happen, and also that it doesn't warn.

Comment: updated my answer. Hope that's more understandable ?